# QT 4.6 Crashing before main

Tags: c++, qt, exception, access-violation

I have an application that uses QT 4.6. My program compiles just fine however when ran I get an access violation which may be seen down below.

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FF693FC2A6C in Rewynd.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000000000000000.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

I did some investigation and this is caused when a pointer non-initialized pointer is deferenced which I would be able to easily fix, but... the crash occurs in WinMain which QT handles. I did some debugging and the crash occurs in the following code.

```
extern "C" int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR /*cmdParamarg*/, int /* cmdShow */)
{
    int argc;
    wchar_t **argvW = CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLineW(), &argc);
    if (!argvW)
        return -1;
    char **argv = new char *[argc + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
        argv[i] = wideToMulti(CP_ACP, argvW[i]);//Crash occurs right here
    argv[argc] = Q_NULLPTR;
    LocalFree(argvW);
    const int exitCode = main(argc, argv);
    for (int i = 0; i < argc && argv[i]; ++i)
        delete [] argv[i];
    delete [] argv;
    return exitCode;
}
```

//////EDIT/////
The crash happens because argv is still null for some reason

[image: Completely lost]

I have no control over the above code and my program didn't initially crash at this point and in addition to that my main is never actually executed so I'm at a loss as for what the issue is.

Comment: Can't help much with what we have--and afraid I'm going to vote to close over a lack of [mcve]--but you say this "didn't initially crash at this point". Take a good long look at what you changed between now and when you didn't have this problem. You may find a few hints or you may find some Undefined Behaviour that says the program never worked, but previously hid this problem. I wish you the former.

Comment: The bug may occur in code handled by Qt, but that doesn't mean that's where is the initial cause. Please show us more of your code, starting with your main function and the main classes of your project. Also what compiler are you using? Are you sure you're linking to the right version of Qt's libraries at runtime?

Comment: What line is actually causing the exception?

Comment: I marked the line causing the exception in the codeblock with a comment. 

<//Crash occurs right here>

In order to troubleshoot the issue I went ahead and removed all code that was written before the crash began to manifest. Which is why I turned to here. Not sure how much more relevant info I can provide considering the barebones project isn't working. I'm wondering if something in the project settings did this? I'm using Visual Studio 2015 with the QTPackage plugin.